# How can I fix this display size issue in Windows 7 Character Map?

Tags: windows-7, characters, fontconfig

The last few times I've opened the character map (Win 7), the "highlighted" character and the "selected" characters have shown up very tiny.  Clicking on a character to highlight it makes it even tinier than before it was highlighted; this used to make it bigger (approximately filling the expanded box).  Then, when you click the select button to move it down into the "characters to copy" text box, it's so small as to be unreadable.

I've searched the web and couldn't find anyone else who had the same issue, and the program doesn't seem to have any settings.  Of course I use the Character Map infrequently enough that I can't pin down exactly when this happened; anywhere from a few weeks ago to several months ago.  Anyone know why this happened or how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Reset your "theme" from one theme to another then back again (because some of the font metrics are in them) . If that does not work reset your DPI, which means to boot, and set it back again. I have never seen it before, but that is what I would try first, it would not be the first time win7 has shown font size oddly. Nice pic of the problem there.

Comment: @Psycogeek Going from a custom theme to the Windows 7 default theme didn't do it.  Could you explain more about resetting DPI? ---- Thanks about the pic.  SE frustrates me when it says things like: You can't embed pics unless you have 10 rep (gee, that's helpful).  Thanks to Nikolay for converting my link to an embedded pic.

Comment: Do you mean screen resolution?

Comment: Changing screen resolution to 800 x 600 and back didn't do it.

Comment: In display the DPI , it is actually back one from the resolution settings. |Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display| (it doesnt sound like any of that is working already). What happens if you change the font to simple arial or system , or Ms sans or something that is more used/tested? or is it specific to that font?

Comment: Found the DPI setting, and I see what you mean about booting.  Back in a bit.

Comment: @Psycogeek Took a while so save/close everything, then the computer really bogged down with the alternate DPI setting, but I'm back and the issue still exists.

Comment: My entire char map is rather tiny and the chars are so small it is difficult to tell what they are. This used to not be this way. Seems it broke with some windows update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font used, in the “Font” dropdown menu. It has now Cambria Math chosen, and probably Character Map scales down the glyphs due to the very large default line height of Cambria Math. In any case, there does not seem to be any way to make the font larger.

Consider using other tools, such as the character map in Microsoft Word, opened via Insert → Symbol. It does not suffer from the problem. Or you might use my online [Full Unicode Input](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8) utility. (It does not currently let you set the font; instead, it tries to show all characters that are present in some of the fonts in your system.)

Comment: Strange.  I thought I'd seen it on other fonts, but it does seem to be tied to just Cambria Math.  Even when I hit the select button and place a character from another font, and a character from Cambria Math into the "Characters to copy" textbox, the first will show up ... readable (some fonts are larger, others smaller) but the Cambria Math will be almost a dot.

Comment: One distinct advantage the Character Map has over Word's insert symbol feature and your unicode utility is the ability to search the character descriptions (which I use all the time).  Something to consider if you're interested in cracking open your utility and revising it. :)

Comment: @TravisBemrose, I can see a similar problem with Asana Math, a free font with a large repertoire of math symbols – and a large line height. With XITS Math, the basic display of characters shows them in very small size.